# Kendo Ui add on change action drop down list on grid column

Tags: kendo-ui

I want to add onchange action for the drop down lists on this example:

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/foreignkeycolumn.html

I need to send row id to this function.

Comment: You need to give some more description here with some code you have tried so far..

Answer (score 2):

If you see [this example](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html) you can specify a custom editor for a column and do what ever you need in that method like this,

```
 function categoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
                    $('<input required data-text-field="CategoryName" data-value-field="CategoryID" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                        .appendTo(container)
                        .kendoDropDownList({
                            autoBind: false,
                            select: function(e) {
                                var item = e.item;
                               var text = item.text();
                               // Use the selected item or its text
                             },                          
                             dataSource: {
                                type: "odata",
                                transport: {
                                    read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Categories"
                                }
                            }
                        });
                }
```